FastAPI : sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This session is in 'committed' state; no further SQL can be emitted within this transaction
I am using fastapi along with starlette-admin for my project. when I try to delete an file saved entry from starlette-admin table I get the a large error, this is the last line of the same.

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This session is in 'committed' state; no further SQL can be emitted within this transaction.

I checked the code thoroughly and when I upload file I make sure I commit after i do add but still error occurs
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

@router.post(
    "/doc_upload", dependencies=[Depends(JWTBearer())]
)
async def active_account_completion_document_upload(
    request: Request,
    form_file: UploadFile = File(...),
    db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db),
):
    document_data = {
        "file_category": file_category,
        "file": file_object,
        "file_name": updated_name,
        "file_size": file_size,
        "file_type": file_type,
        "upload_timestamp": upload_timestamp,
        "uploader_id": current_user.id,
        "storage_folder": upload_folder_path,
        "file_url": file_url,
    }
    db_document = UserDocument(**document_data)
    db.add(db_document)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_document)


this is the full error i get

127.0.0.1:40504 - "GET /api/user-document/row-action?name=delete&pk=288 HTTP/1.1" 500
Internal Server Error ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py",
line 98, in receive
return self.receive_nowait()   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py",
line 93, in receive_nowait
raise WouldBlock anyio.WouldBlock
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py",
line 78, in call_next
message = await recv_stream.receive()   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py",
line 118, in receive
raise EndOfStream anyio.EndOfStream
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette_admin/contrib/sqla/middleware.py",
line 35, in get_session
yield session   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette_admin/contrib/sqla/middleware.py",
line 28, in dispatch
return await call_next(request)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py",
line 84, in call_next
raise app_exc   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py",
line 70, in coro
await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect, send_no_error)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/sessions.py",
line 86, in call
await self.app(scope, receive, send_wrapper)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py",
line 108, in call
response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette_admin/auth.py",
line 286, in dispatch
return await call_next(request)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py",
line 84, in call_next
raise app_exc   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py",
line 70, in coro
await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect, send_no_error)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py",
line 79, in call
raise exc   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py",
line 68, in call
await self.app(scope, receive, sender)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py",
line 718, in call
await route.handle(scope, receive, send)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py",
line 276, in handle
await self.app(scope, receive, send)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py",
line 66, in app
response = await func(request)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette_admin/base.py",
line 357, in handle_row_action
handler_return = await model.handle_row_action(request, pk, name)   File
"/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py",
line 155, in handle_row_action
return await super().handle_row_action(request, pk, name)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette_admin/views.py",
line 451, in handle_row_action
handler_return = await handler(request, pk)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette_admin/views.py",
line 506, in row_action_3_delete
await self.delete(request, [pk])   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py",
line 453, in delete
await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(session.commit)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py",
line 33, in run_sync
return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py",
line 877, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
return await future   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py",
line 807, in run
result = context.run(func, *args)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
line 1969, in commit
trans.commit(_to_root=True)   File "", line 2, in commit   File
"/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py",
line 139, in _go
ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
line 1266, in commit
self.session.dispatch.after_commit(self.session)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py",
line 378, in call
fn(*args, **kw)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy_file/types.py",
line 226, in _after_commit
cls.delete_files(getattr(session, "_old_files", set()), "after_commit")   File
"/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy_file/types.py",
line 170, in delete_files
StorageManager.delete_file(path)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy_file/storage.py",
line 138, in delete_file
obj = StorageManager.get(upload_storage).get_object(file_id)   File
"/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libcloud/storage/base.py",
line 199, in get_object
return self.driver.get_object(container_name=self.name, object_name=object_name)   File
"/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libcloud/storage/drivers/local.py", line 367, in get_object
return self._make_object(container, object_name)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libcloud/storage/drivers/local.py", line 242, in _make_object
raise ObjectDoesNotExistError(value=None, driver=self, object_name=object_name)
libcloud.storage.types.ObjectDoesNotExistError:
<ObjectDoesNotExistError in
<libcloud.storage.drivers.local.LocalStorageDriver object at
0x7f1055c79330>, value=None, object = None>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py",
line 426, in run_asgi
result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py",
line 84, in call
return await self.app(scope, receive, send)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py",
line 1106, in call
await super().call(scope, receive, send)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py",
line 122, in call
await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py",
line 184, in call
raise exc   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py",
line 162, in call
await self.app(scope, receive, _send)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py",
line 79, in call
raise exc   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py",
line 68, in call
await self.app(scope, receive, sender)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py",
line 20, in call
raise e   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py",
line 17, in call
await self.app(scope, receive, send)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py",
line 718, in call
await route.handle(scope, receive, send)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py",
line 443, in handle
await self.app(scope, receive, send)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py",
line 122, in call
await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py",
line 184, in call
raise exc   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py",
line 162, in call
await self.app(scope, receive, _send)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py",
line 108, in call
response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette_admin/contrib/sqla/middleware.py",
line 26, in dispatch
with get_session(self.engine) as session:   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py",
line 153, in exit
self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette_admin/contrib/sqla/middleware.py",
line 37, in get_session
session.rollback()   File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
line 1931, in rollback
self._transaction.rollback(_to_root=True)   File "", line 2, in rollback   File
"/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py",
line 103, in _go
self._raise_for_prerequisite_state(fn.name, current_state)   File
"/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
line 952, in _raise_for_prerequisite_state
raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(

I checked in detail and i think it has to do with how i configured the file upload, as this error occurs at
File "/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/envs/virtual_env_name/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libcloud/storage/drivers/local.py", line 242, in _make_object raise ObjectDoesNotExistError(value=None, driver=self, object_name=object_name) libcloud.storage.types.ObjectDoesNotExistError: <ObjectDoesNotExistError in <libcloud.storage.drivers.local.LocalStorageDriver object at 0x7fbdf553e050>, value=None, object = None>
this is how I configured the storage
from sqlalchemy_file.storage import StorageManager
from libcloud.storage.drivers.local import LocalStorageDriver

project_root_folder = settings.PROJECT_FOLDER
file_upload_path = "/backend/app/app/uploads/user_documents"
upload_folder_path = project_root_folder + file_upload_path

os.makedirs(upload_folder_path, 0o777, exist_ok=True)
my_container = LocalStorageDriver(upload_folder_path).get_container("user_documents")
StorageManager.add_storage("user_documents", my_container)

and this is how i used used it in the endpoint
                            file_object = CustomFile(
                                content=file_contents, filename=updated_name
                            )
                            file_url = generate_file_url(updated_name)
                            document_data = {
                                "file_category": file_category,
                                "file": file_object,
                                "file_name": updated_name,
                                "file_size": file_size,
                                "file_type": file_type,
                                "upload_timestamp": upload_timestamp,
                                "uploader_id": current_user.id,
                                "storage_folder": upload_folder_path,
                                "file_url": file_url,
                            }
                            db_document = UserDocument(**document_data)
                            db.add(db_document)
                            db.commit()
                            db.refresh(db_document)

where CustomFile is
from sqlalchemy_file import File as SQLAlchemyFile

class CustomFile(SQLAlchemyFile):
    def get_extension_from_content_type(self) -> Optional[str]:
        """Extract extension from content type."""
        if "/" in self.content_type:
            _, extension = self.content_type.split("/")
            return "." + extension
        return None

    def save_to_storage(self, upload_storage: Optional[str] = None) -> None:
        """Save current file into provided `upload_storage`."""
        extra = self.get("extra", {})
        extra.update({"content_type": self.content_type})

        metadata = self.get("metadata", None)
        if metadata is not None:
            warnings.warn(
                'metadata attribute is deprecated. Use extra={"meta_data": ...} instead',
                DeprecationWarning,
                stacklevel=1,
            )
            extra.update({"meta_data": metadata})

        if extra.get("meta_data", None) is None:
            extra["meta_data"] = {}
        extra["meta_data"].update(
            {"filename": self.filename, "content_type": self.content_type}
        )
        stored_file = self.store_content(
            self.original_content,
            upload_storage,
            extra=extra,
            headers=self.get("headers", None),
            content_path=self.content_path,
        )
        self["file_id"] = stored_file.name
        self["upload_storage"] = upload_storage
        self["uploaded_at"] = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
        self["path"] = f"{upload_storage}/{stored_file.name}"
        self["url"] = stored_file.get_cdn_url()
        self["saved"] = True

    def store_content(
        self,
        content: Any,
        upload_storage: Optional[str] = None,
        name: Optional[str] = None,
        metadata: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
        extra: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
        headers: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = None,
        content_path: Optional[str] = None,
    ) -> StoredFile:
        """Store content into provided `upload_storage`
        with additional `metadata`. Can be used by processors
        to store additional files.
        """
        stored_file = StorageManager.save_file(
            name=extra["meta_data"]["filename"],
            content=content,
            upload_storage=upload_storage,
            metadata=metadata,
            extra=extra,
            headers=headers,
            content_path=content_path,
        )
        self["files"].append(f"{upload_storage}/{name}")
        return stored_file


I'm not familiar with starlett-admin, but it's possible that there is already an open transaction in db (you don't show how db is obtained), in whcih case manually committing may cause problems.  What happens if you remove your commit?

hi i have updated how I import db, please check
